# Unable to get a PHP array to display its contents in reverse

Tags: php, arrays

I've spent a lot of time looking at methods to do this and functions yet not been  able to get the contents to display to screen in reverse.

I want to show the most recent entries in a blog at the top of the list. So here's what I have so far but the array doesn't seem to be reversing and neither is the while loop working that displays the elements that I want (I used print_r and var_dump just for debugging.

```
<body class="body">

<ul>

<?php

include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$sql = 'SELECT post_id AS "id", post_title AS "title", post_datetime AS "datetime" FROM posts WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL';
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


while (($post = $res->fetch_assoc())){
    echo current($post);
}

array_reverse_keys($post);

foreach ($post as $value) {
    print_r($value);
}

while ($post) {
    ?>
    <li>
    <?php
    if (isset($post)) { 
        ?>  
        <a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>">
        <?php echo $post['title']?></a>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </li>

    <?php
} 
?> 
</ul> 

<?php
$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The function being called reads:

```
<?php 
    function array_reverse_keys($ar){ 
      return array_reverse(array_reverse($ar,true),false); 
    }
?>
```

Can anyone assist please?

Kind regards,

Mark

Comment: The function being called reads: <?php 
    function array_reverse_keys($ar){ 
      return array_reverse(array_reverse($ar,true),false); 
    }
  ?>

Comment: It looks like you are reversing the reversed array. Why not just do array_reverse($ar,true);

Comment: `$post` is an associative array containing the last row that was returned by the query. Are you sure that's what you want to reverse? You're rearranging the column names and values when you do this.

Comment: Your `while ($post)` is an infinite loop, since `$post` never changes in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The simplest way was to read in the array in reverse from SQL which avoided the PHP coding altogether. I should have spotted this and feel pretty humbled for missing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sql add order by clause 
eg:

```
$sql="SELECT post_id AS "id", post_title AS "title", post_datetime AS "datetime" FROM posts WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL order by id DESC";
```

Comment: This was the simplest way of doing it and the one I felt that I best understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning the new array, but you're not using the returned value when you call it. It should be:

```
$post = array_reverse_keys($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
array_reverse_keys($post);
```

to

```
$post = array_reverse_keys($post);
```

Comment: Isn't that what I said in my answer 15 minutes earlier?

Comment: Stack Snippets only work for HTML/Javascript. You can't run PHP with it.